# How to mock component method using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that has a text `input` as one of the children inside the main wrapper. When the `input` gains focus it calls a function via its `onFocus` property. So the component's structure is something like this:

`<div className="main-wrapper">
  <input type="text" onFocus={this.focusHandler} />
</div>`

Elsewhere in the class there is a method named `focusHandler` that looks something like this

`focusHandler = () => {
  //Do whatever it is that focus handlers do.
  //In this case that involves changing the local state, so there is something like
  this.setState({ fieldHasFocus: true });
}`

What I would like to do is to have a test (in Jest) that would verify that when the input gains focus the `focusHandler()` method is called. However, I can't figure out how to put a mock into my test for `focusHandler()` and to  check whether or not it is called when I `simulate('focus')` on the input field.

Comment: Why you want to mock this instead of testing the state of the component after `simulate('focus')`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle This is a question I've had myself. Is it better to test whether the direct result of the action occurs, in this case `focusHandler()` being called, or whether the result of that action occurs, in this case the state being changed? Or is it better to test both at once? It seems that testing the direct result of the action should be of greater importance since the state could be changed by something else. Then perhaps a second test should be written to see if the state changes when the function is called? Or is that overkill?

Answer (score 1):

You can spy on the *before* you render the component. You don't need to force update the instance of the component. Declare the spy function at the top of the file before your spec/`describe` block.

```
const focusHandlerSpy = jest.spyOn(YourComponent.prototype, 'focusHandler');
```

Then ...

```
describe('When the input field is focused', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    component.find('input').simulate('focus');
  });

  it('should invoke the focusHandlerSpy function', () => {
    expect(focusHandlerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: it gives this error: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent />);
const focusHandlerSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'focusHandler');
wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();
```

Now your `focusHandlerSpy` will be called on focus.